# Working with Makefile, source generators and generating dependencies with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

In the project I have:

- `main.cpp`
- `template.sth`
- much more

For each `.cpp` file I am generating `.o` file.
Thanks to that I could write simple rule for all `.o` targets (simplified, a little bit pseudcode version for more clarity):

```
OBJS = #list of all .o files needed

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -MM -MF %.d -MP -MT %.o %.cpp
    g++ -c -o %.o %.cpp
```

Then I am including all existing `.d` files, so after each generation I am refreshing dependencies.

It worked unless I had `template.sth`. This file contains some template for generating `h` files and `cpp` files.

When  one file, i.e. `main.cpp` includes file generated from `template.sth` (lets say `gen.h`):

1. Instruction generating `.d` file doesn't work, because `gen.h` is missing:
   `fatal error: gen.h: No such file or directory`  `include "gen.h"`
2. Even if these instructions would work there is a problem with my "workflow". Untill now I could generate `.d` file for next make. It worked, because adding new dependencies require to change one of current dependecnies. So after adding one `.o` is rebuilding and new `.d` is generated. Now I need to detect that before making `.o` I need to generate `gen.h` from `template.sth`.

Is there any way to do it automatically? Problem 1. could be solved if there is some way to tell `g++` that if some `.h` file is missing it can just add it to dependencies.
After solving problem 1. executing make multiple times (I think twice is always enough) end up with built project (first `make` would generate dependencies files, then second `make` sees that `main.cpp` depends on `gen.h`, `gen.h` is missing and there is instruction how to create `gen.h` so it will create `gen.h` before building `main.o`).

If it can't be done somehow automatically, how can it be solved? Can I write in `Makefile` instructions which will build all generated files before any other or I need to manually add this generated file as dependencies in all `.o` instructions?

**UPDATE:**

After few changes, with `-MG` flag `g++` generates correct files even for `gen.h`. I can build my project now with two `make` commands.
First one will create correct `.d` files and break, because `gen.h` is missing.
Second one will have `.d` files ready, so it will generate `gen.h` before building `main.o`, so building `main.o` will be successful.

Is there a way to generate `.d` file and then use it, before generating `.o`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependencies for the generated files:

```
gen.h: template.sth
        ...command to create gen.h from template.sth
```

If you have lots of generated files, you might want a way of creating those dependencies automatically, which would depend on how you are generating them.

In addition, you want to generate the .d files independently from the .o files and use the `-MG` flag while generating them to ignore missing files:

```
%.d: %.cpp
        g++ -MM -MF $@ -MP -MG $<

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

This way, the first time you run make, it will generate the `.d` files with the dependencies and then reread them and recompute all the dependencies before trying to build anything else.

Comment: I have this. The problem is that there is no dependency in Makefile between main.o and gen.h.

Comment: @Ari Is it correct that you are looking for an automatic way to add `gen.h` to the dependency list of `main.o` ?  Note that object files depend on all headers they include, so dependencies like `main.o → gen.h` should be in your Makefile wether `gen.h` has been generated or not.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Yes, the same way as I'm adding not-generated dependencies.

Comment: You must explicitly add a dependency on the generated header file.  Generated header files (like all derived objects) cannot be auto-detected.  Only source files can be auto-detected.